# Why is MSACCESS parameter query showing duplicate rows?

Tags: parameters, ms-access-2010

OK.. Weird one.

Query 1 which links 2 tables against a unique ID generates 23 rows of data for a specific unique ID in primary table.

Not my database, but the unique field is TEXT

Query 2 is based on query 1

If the search field is queried with an exact match field it gives 23 rows.

If it uses a defined parameter with =

=[File Number?]

Defined as Text parameter, it returns 23 rows

If it is entered as

Like [File Number?] it returns 46 rows

But there are no equivalent entries to the number entered, and the field itself shows a unique number

eg.

If 1234 was entered to get the 23 rows, it would return 46 rows with like and all would have 1234 only in the search field.

Maybe Lockdown has eroded my braincells..

Any suggestions as to why.

I changed it to the = version.

There were no wild cards * within the query or entered within the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is as follows

= will return the exact match
like will return exact match and any record containing the exact match as part of the values

further explanation is below
If searching for values 1234
= will return an exact match, i.e. every record where 1234 exists in the fields been searched by.

While Like will return

1. every where there is 1234 existing in the fields searched by
2. every where there is 1234???????????   as long as 1234 is part of the values.

Comment: This is NOT strictly true though is it.
Like "1234*" would return that.
But Like "1234" does NOT return the equivalent of begins with nor contains.

I have tested this and even if records begin with 1234, they are not returned by Like "1234", that returns no records.

So unfortunately that question is open....

This is also the case with SQL server and using

Like '1234'   or Like '1234%'

Answer (score 0):

Like 'b?'
Result: all values that start with b and are 2 characters in length

So if you use a field [File Number?] and you enter 1234 it will search and return the string entered 1234 and any one more string.

So using your example of like  1234? it will return

Result: all values that start with 1234 and are 5 characters in length

You can check the below links for further explanation

https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931

Comment: Do you really need to post 2 separate answers to this question? Consider editing your previous answer to include the additional information.

Comment: Its because the second answer gives another perspective to the solution

Comment: Ok, if each of the answers stands on its own as a solution, that's fine. Just checking, since this is not a common situation.

Comment: Nope...
All standard query stuff and NOT true
If a field has an entries for 1234 and also 12345
Then a search string query as
Like "1234?" will indeed return 5 in length beginning 1234
likewise 
Like "1234*" will return anything beginning 1234
However IF a Parameter is used [Enter No?]
Like [Enter Number?] the ? is part of the parameter name and is NOT a single character wild card.
Hence the parameter Like [Enter Number?] and when prompted entering 1234 into the parameter box, will ONLY return 4 character values, unless 1234? or 1234* where actually entered as the parameter values.